How might I make this function work as intended or more simple?
I want to convert lines of text to simple markdown table.
e.g.: I want to go from:
Irrigation system   Evaporation replacement (%)     Frequency
Overhead sprinklers (Perth)     140     1 to 2 times daily
Overhead sprinklers (South-West)    90  Every 5 days (on average, apply 25mm)

to:
Irrigation system                 Evaporation replacement (%)  Frequency
-----------------                 ---------------------------  ---------
Overhead sprinklers (Perth)       140                          1 to 2 times daily
Overhead sprinklers (South-West)  90                           Every 5 days (on average, apply 25mm)

(Note about input lines: column separators are tabs with or without adjacent space OR more than one space.)
I have the following that works:
function! DashTable()
    call WriteDashTable()
    call WriteDashUnderTableHeader()
endfunction

function! WriteDashTable()
    " restore visual selection
    normal! gv
    
    " Convert tabs to two spaces within the selection
    silent! '<,'>s/\t/  /ge

    " Replace two or more spaces with tabs
    silent! '<,'>s/\s\{2,}/\t/ge

    " Columnate selection on tabs
    silent! '<,'>!column -t -s $'\t'

endfunction

function! WriteDashUnderTableHeader()
    " Go to beginning of previous visual selection
    exe "normal! '<"

    " ??? Need this twice to paste line??
    normal yyp
    normal yyp

    " replace with dashes
    s/\S/-/g
    s/- -/---/g
endfunc

vmap <M-j> :<C-u>call DashTable()<CR>

My questions are:

I failed to get the desired output via visual selection calling function directly without mapping beginning with :<C-u> to cancel visual selection. I would rather not have a mapping and have just a function to call.
So, how can I call a function over a visual selection and at some point not operate over all lines without creating a mapping as above?

With function WriteDashUnderTableHeader() I need this line normal yyp twice. What's going on here?


FIXED
This is satisfactory:
function! DashTable() range
    for line in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        " Replace tabs with two spaces
        execute 'silent! ' . line . 's/\t/  /ge'
        " Replace two or more spaces with tabs
        execute 'silent! ' . line . 's/\s\{2,}/\t/ge'
    endfor
    " Columnate selection on tabs
    execute 'silent! ' . a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . "!column -t -s $'\t'"
    " copy first line after first line
    execute a:firstline . 'co ' . a:firstline
    " replace non-space chars with dash
    execute (a:firstline+1) . 's/\S/-/g'
    " replace single spaces between dash with all dashes
    execute (a:firstline+1) . 's/- -/---/g'
endfunction

vmap <M-j> :call DashTable()<CR>

Thanks for the help, learned a bit as well 

Re yyp, have you tried normal! instead of normal?

You could use a range function:
function DashTable() range
  for line in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    execute 'silent! ' . line . 's/\t/  /ge'

    " Replace two or more spaces with tabs
    execute 'silent! ' . line . 's/\s\{2,}/\t/ge'
  endfor
  " Columnate selection on tabs
  execute 'silent! ' . a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . "!column -t -s $'\t'"
  execute a:firstline . 't ' . a:firstline
  execute (a:firstline+1) . 's/\S/-/g'
  execute (a:firstline+1) . 's/- -/---/g'
endfunction

vmap <M-j> :call DashTable()<CR>

I do not manage to reproduce your yyp problem. But I would rewrite:
" Go to beginning of previous visual selection
exe "normal! '<"

" ??? Need this twice to paste line??
normal yyp
normal yyp

into:
'<yank
'<put



I failed to get the desired output via visual selection calling function directly without mapping beginning with :<C-u> to cancel visual selection.

From :h :call
        When a range is given and the function doesn't handle it
        itself, the function is executed for each line in the range,
        with the cursor in the first column of that line.

So if you want to execute function call only once you need either drop the range by prepending <c-u>, or use :h <cmd> modifier (that forbids switching to cmdline mode and therefore never adds a range at all), or add :h :func-range attribute (that forces Vim to make single call of this function).
However, imo, it is better to create a command and pass range directly. That is,
command -range DashTable call s:dash_table(<line1>, <line2>)

function s:dash_table(line1, line2) abort
    " Do something with text starting from a:line1 upto a:line2
endfunction

This way the function is not bound to Visual mode but also works with Normal mode with v:count and such. And also, you don't need to type call every time.

With function WriteDashUnderTableHeader() I need this line normal yyp twice.

That shouldn't be so.
